# Saving [NSTextField stringValue]... variable is cleared when my window closes?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

So I grab the username from the field, save it in an NSString variable:

```
    loggedInUser = [usernameField stringValue];
    [loginWindow close];
```

Later, I try to access that `loggedInUser` data:

```
    NSLog(@"Logged in User:%@", loggedInUser);
```

This often, but not always, gives an error:

```
    Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". // Summary displays "{...}" for the value
```

The `loggedInUser` NSString gets cleared? What happened? (I never modify this value myself).

My only thought is that I am somehow saving the *continued* value of the NSTextField in the NSString. Then, when I close the window, that value is cleared.

Is that what's happening? How do I save that Textfield value in a safe way for continued use?

Comment: if you're talking about NSTextFields, why do you have this tagged with cocoa-touch and ios tags?

Comment: When you create and show the window, what does [`[yourWindow isReleasedWhenClosed]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/isReleasedWhenClosed) return? I suspect your window (and it's contents) gets released right after you close it.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, why does the `isReleasedWhenClosed` property matter? That's the point of this question I guess. I'm saving the username text data into a global (is that the right term?) NSString. So after I've saved it there, why does it matter what I do to the original characters?

Comment: @cksubs: He answered that in his comment. If `releasedWhenClosed` is turned on, then the window releases itself when you close it. When the window is deallocated, it releases its content view, which releases all of its subviews, etc.—so eventually the text field is released, so if you're not owning the string yourself, the string dies out from under you. That's the “bad access”: You're trying to work with a dead object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahhh, I just realized what is going on.

When you close your window (and it likely gets released), the string that you assigned to your object's NSString variable is autoreleased as well.

You need to explicitly retain it.

Or, more to the point, do this:

```
loggedInUser = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [usernameField stringValue]];
```

or:

```
loggedInUser = [[usernameField stringValue] copy];
```

don't forget to release `loggedInUser` when your `dealloc` method is called (assuming you're not using ARC here).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to store the string in a property rather than an instance variable. You could declare the property as `strong` (or `retain`) or `copy`, and you would then own the string (or a copy of it).

You mention that the variable “is cleared” when the string dies, but in fact that is not the case. The variable *is not* cleared, which is the cause of the crash: It still holds the pointer to a now-dead object. Keeping it alive with `strong` or `copy` is one solution, but another option, if you migrate to ARC, would be to declare the property as `weak`. Then, on Mac OS X 10.7 and later, the property will be cleared (set to `nil`) as soon as the string dies.